# Problems with adding network printer Mac OS

Tags: macos, network-printer

Hey there I have 2 questions...

How does Mac OS decides which printers are being listed on this page...

System Preferences -> Printers & Scanners

and then if you click on the + sign

and in the add windows the list which says Default...

On which preferences does Mac OS decides which printers are listed here ?

Because I have one problem with a network printer. If I add the printer there from the add printer page it works.
But if I am trying to add the printer via command line and lpadmin the printer doesn't work

Comment: It shows printers detected via the Bonjour (aka multicast DNS) protocol. After adding it via Printers & Scanners, try running `lpstat -v` to see what that's adding. Without more info about the printer and how you're trying to add it, it's hard to give any more specific suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the printer is added with smb:  if I add the printer with lpadmin and smb it gives me the waiting for authentication error. If I add the same printer with lpd no print jobs coming out